# socket emit an event on http PUT

Tags: express, socket.io

I am using `expressjs`, `nedb`, and `socket.io`. Various (non-browser) clients are able to `PUT` new values into the db successfully. When that happens, I want a message emitted to all browsers connected to the server. I have the following code which is currently not sending a message back to the browser.

```
// on the server
//***************************************************************

// reachable to the world at http://server/foo
// clients can PUT data into the db
app.put('/foo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

    db.insert(req.body, function (err, newDoc) {
        io.sockets.emit('PUT a new value', { added: newDoc._id });
        res.send('Success! Find it again with id: ' + newDoc._id);
    });
});

// reachable to the world at http://server/
// browser shows a dashboard of events
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // code to serve the dashboard here
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('foo', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('PUT a new value', data);
    })
});


// in the browser
//***************************************************************

var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.on('PUT a new value', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Data get inserted into the db successfully from different non-browser clients, but the connected browser doesn't receive an update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the browser connects  to the server with socket.io ? Does the browser receive other socket.io events than 'PUT a new value' ?

Comment: I think I've figured out the cause of my failure, but still don't know how to solve it. The problem is because my router files are separate from app.js. So the instance of io instantiated in app.js is not available in '/foo' (I simplified the code above. Actually put('/foo') is not in app.js but in a separate file at ./routers/foo.js. If I move the code from foo.js to app.js, it works. So, I have to figure out how to pass around the declared object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following app structure generated by `express generator`. I start the app with `$ DEBUG=foo:* npm start`

```
.
|____app.js
|____bin
| |____www
|____data
|____LICENSE
|____node_modules
|____package.json
|____public
| |____stylesheets
| |____javascripts
| |____images
|____README.md
|____routes
| |____index.js
| |____readings.js
| |____sensors.js
| |____users.js
|____views
| |____error.hjs
| |____index.hjs
```

In app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var io = require('socket.io')();
app.io = io;

// notice the `(io)` for the routes that need to be socket-aware
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var sensors = require('./routes/sensors');
var readings = require('./routes/readings')(io);

…

// start listening with socket.io
app.io.on('connection', function(socket){  
    console.log('a user connected');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Then in ./routes/readings.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(io) {
    router.put('/', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

        db.insert(req.body, function (err, newDoc) {
            io.emit("reading", {id: newDoc._id});
            res.send('Success PUTting data! id: ' + newDoc._id);
        });
    });

    return router;
}
```

Finally, in the index.hjs template for the client-side

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('reading', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

The above works. When data are inserted into the db via an http `PUT` (see readings.js), an event is emitted by `io.emit('reading', data)` and the browser receives that event and shows it in the console with `socket.on('reading', function (data) { … });`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which I don't like at all but it works. We can add `io` object to `req` or to `res` in the middleware like that:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.io = io;
  next();
});
```

before `app.use('/', routes)` and then in our router module we "import" the `io` object:

```
    app.put('/foo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
      if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

      db.insert(req.body, function (err, newDoc) {
        var io = req.io;   // HERE !!!
        io.sockets.emit('PUT a new value', { added: newDoc._id });
        res.send('Success! Find it again with id: ' + newDoc._id);
      });
    });
```

I know, I know... let's find something else :-)

Comment: I added my solution as an answer. It works, and unless I find something more elegant, I am happy with it.

Comment: Your solution is very nice